# Cannot iterate through two lists at once python

Tags: python, list

I am having a problem with my python code, but I am not sure what it is. I am creating a program that creates a table with all possible combinations of four digits provided the digits do not repeat, which I know is successful. Then, I create another table and attempt to add to this secondary table all of the values which use the same numbers in a different order (so I do not have, say, 1234, 4321, 3241, 3214, 1324, 2413, etc. on this table.) However, this does not seem to be working, as the second table has only one value. What have I done wrong? My code is below. Oh, and I know that the one value comes from appending the 1 at the top.

```
    combolisttwo = list()
    combolisttwo.append(1)
    combolist = {(a, b, c, d) for a in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0} for b in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0} for c in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0} for d in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0} if a != b and a != c and a != d and b != c and b != d and c!=d}
    for i in combolist:
        x = 0
        letternums = str(i)
        letters = list(letternums)
        for g in letters:
            n = 0
            hits = 0
            nonhits = 0
            letterstwo = str(combolisttwo[n])
            if g == letterstwo[n]:
                hits = hits + 1
            if g != letterstwo[n]:
                nonhits = nonhits + 1
            if hits == 4:
                break
            if hits + nonhits == 4:
                combolisttwo.append(i)
                break




    x = len(combolisttwo)

    print (x)
```

Comment: have you tried the zip() function?

Answer (score 4):

*All possible combinations of four digits provided the digits do not repeat*:

```
import itertools as IT
combolist = list(IT.combinations(range(10), 4))
```

*Then, I create another table and attempt to add to this secondary table all of the values which use the same numbers in a different order (so I do not have, say, 1234, 4321, 3241, 3214, 1324, 2413, etc. on this table.)*:

```
combolist2 = [item for combo in combolist
              for item in IT.permutations(combo, len(combo))]
```

---

Useful references:

- [combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) -- for enumerating collections of elements without replacement
- [permutations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) -- for enumerating collections of elements in all possible orders

Comment: This creates combolist2 as a table with that problem (1234, 4321, 3241, 3214, 1324, 2413, etc.) I know this because it returns the same value (5040) as ... combolist = {(a, b, c, d) for a in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0} for b in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0} for c in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0} for d in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0} if a != b and a != c and a != d and b != c and b != d and c!=d}

Answer (score 2):

This code is pretty confused ;-)  For example, you have `n = 0` in your inner loop, but never set `n` to anything else.  For another, you have `x = 0`, but never use `x`.  Etc.

Using `itertools` is really best, but if you're trying to learn how to do these things yourself, that's fine.  For a start, change your:

```
    letters = list(letternums)
```

to

```
    letters = list(letternums)
    print(letters)
    break
```

I bet you'll be surprised at what you see!  The elements of your `combolist` are tuples, so when you do `letternums = str(i)` you get a string with a mix of digits, spaces, parentheses and commas.  I don't think you're **expecting** anything but digits.

Your `letterstwo` is the string "1" (always, because you never change `n`).  But it doesn't much matter, because you set `hits` and `nonhits` to 0 **every** time your `for g in letters` loop iterates.  So `hits` and `nonhits` can never be bigger than 1.

Which answers your literal question ;-)  `combolisttwo.append(i)` is never executed because 
`hits + nonhits == 4` is never true.  That's why `combolisttwo` remains at its initial value (`[1]`).

Put some calls to `print()` in your code?  That will help you see what's going wrong.